# How to resolve Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion Mailchimp Error

Tags: magento2, exception, array, mailchimp, conversion

> Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Select.php on
>   line 244

line 235-244 of the Select.php

```
public function calcOptionHash($optionValue)
{
    return sprintf('%u', crc32($this->getName() . $this->getId() . $optionValue));
}
```

this is when i try to go to mailchimp configuration tab on the admin page.

full exception message here:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Select.php on line 243
#0 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Select.php(243): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Array to string...', '/p...', 243, Array)
#1 /public_html/vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/CustomerMap.php(68): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select->calcOptionHash(Array)
#2 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Field/FieldArray/AbstractFieldArray.php(159): Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\CustomerMap->_prepareArrayRow(Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject))
#3 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/form/field/array.phtml(117): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray->getArrayRows()
#4 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/p...')
#5 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\CustomerMap\Interceptor), '/p...', Array)
#6 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/p...')
#7 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(126): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#8 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Field/FieldArray/AbstractFieldArray.php(262): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#9 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Field/FieldArray/AbstractFieldArray.php(116): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray->_toHtml()
#10 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Field.php(73): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray->_getElementHtml(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Text))
#11 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Field.php(52): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field->_renderValue(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Text))
#12 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field->render(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Text))
#13 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\CustomerMap\Interceptor->___callParent('render', Array)
#14 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\CustomerMap\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Text))
#15 /public_html/generated/code/Ebizmarts/MailChimp/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/CustomerMap/Interceptor.php(26): Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\CustomerMap\Interceptor->___callPlugins('render', Array, Array)
#16 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/AbstractElement.php(459): Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\CustomerMap\Interceptor->render(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Text))
#17 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Text.php(43): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->getHtml()
#18 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/AbstractElement.php(473): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Text->getHtml()
#19 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Fieldset.php(86): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->toHtml()
#20 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Fieldset.php(66): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Fieldset->_getChildrenElementsHtml(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset))
#21 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/AbstractElement.php(459): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Fieldset->render(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset))
#22 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/AbstractElement.php(473): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->getHtml()
#23 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form.php(325): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->toHtml()
#24 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form.php(340): Magento\Framework\Data\Form->toHtml()
#25 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form.php(101): Magento\Framework\Data\Form->getHtml()
#26 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/form.phtml(15): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->getFormHtml()
#27 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/p...')
#28 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form), '/p...', Array)
#29 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/p...')
#30 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(126): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#31 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#32 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#33 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('system\\config\\f...')
#34 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('system\\config\\f...')
#35 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(507): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('system\\config\\f...', true)
#36 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/edit.phtml(22): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('form')
#37 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/p...')
#38 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Edit), '/p...', Array)
#39 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/p...')
#40 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(126): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#41 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#42 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#43 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('system.config.e...')
#44 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('system.config.e...')
#45 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('system.config.e...', false)
#46 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false)
#47 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#48 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false)
#49 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('admin.scope.col...', false)
#50 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('admin.scope.col...')
#51 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('admin.scope.col...', false)
#52 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.col', false)
#53 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.col')
#54 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.col', false)
#55 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.conta...', false)
#56 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#57 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.conta...', false)
#58 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content', false)
#59 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#60 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', false)
#61 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#62 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#63 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#64 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page', false)
#65 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#66 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', false)
#67 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#68 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#69 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root')
#70 /public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#71 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#72 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#73 /public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#74 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#75 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#76 /public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#77 {main}
```

CustomerMap.php code as below

```
<?php
/**
 * mc-magento2 Magento Component
 *
 * @category Ebizmarts
 * @package mc-magento2
 * @author Ebizmarts Team <info@ebizmarts.com>
 * @copyright Ebizmarts (http://ebizmarts.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * @date: 10/27/17 12:01 PM
 * @file: CustomerMap.php
 */

namespace Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

class CustomerMap extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * @var VarsMap
     */
    protected $_varsRenderer=null;
    protected $_mailchimpRenderer=null;

    protected function _getVarsRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->_varsRenderer) {
            $this->_varsRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\VarsMap',
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
            $this->_varsRenderer->setClass('customer_field_select');
        }
        return $this->_varsRenderer;
    }
    protected function _getMailchimpRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->_mailchimpRenderer) {
            $this->_mailchimpRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\MailchimpMap',
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
            $this->_mailchimpRenderer->setClass('mailchimp_field_select');
        }
        return $this->_mailchimpRenderer;
    }

    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
//        $this->addColumn('mailchimp', ['label' => __('Mailchimp')]);
        $this->addColumn(
            'mailchimp_field_id',
            ['label' => __('Mailchimp'), 'renderer' => $this->_getMailchimpRenderer()]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'customer_field_id',
            ['label' => __('Magento'), 'renderer' => $this->_getVarsRenderer()]
        );
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
    }
    protected function _prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $optionExtraAttr = [];
        $optionExtraAttr['option_' . $this->_getVarsRenderer()->calcOptionHash($row->getData('customer_field_id'))] =
            'selected="selected"';
        //$optionExtraAttr['option_' . $this->_getMailchimpRenderer()->calcOptionHash($row->getData('mailchimp_field_id'))] =
        //    'selected="selected"';
        $row->setData(
            'option_extra_attrs',
            $optionExtraAttr
        );
    }
}
```

var/xxx.php.error.log

```
[21-Mar-2019 06:54:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Helper\Data::serialize() in /public_html/vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/Helper/VarsMap.php:99 Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/Helper/VarsMap.php(49): Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Helper\VarsMap->serializeValue(Array)
#1 /public_html/vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/Model/Config/Backend/VarsMap.php(71): Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Helper\VarsMap->makeStorableArrayFieldValue(Array)
#2 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php(406): Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Model\Config\Backend\VarsMap->beforeSave()
#3 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(647): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save(Object(Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Model\Config\Backend\VarsMap\Interceptor))
#4 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Transaction.php(129): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#5 /public_html/vendor/mage in /public_html/vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/Helper/VarsMap.php on line 99
```

VarsMap.php as below

```
<?php
/**
 * mc-magento2 Magento Component
 *
 * @category Ebizmarts
 * @package mc-magento2
 * @author Ebizmarts Team <info@ebizmarts.com>
 * @copyright Ebizmarts (http://ebizmarts.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * @date: 10/27/17 3:41 PM
 * @file: VarsMap.php
 */

namespace Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

class VarsMap extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $_attCollection;
    /**
     * VarsMap constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attCollection,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_attCollection = $attCollection;
    }

    protected function _getCustomerAtt()
    {
        $ret = [];
        $collection = $this->_attCollection->create();
        /**
         * @var $item \Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute
         */
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $ret[$item->getId()] = $item->getFrontendLabel();
        }

        natsort($ret);
        return $ret;
    }

    public function setInputName($value)
    {
        return $this->setName($value);
    }

    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function _toHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->getOptions()) {
            foreach ($this->_getCustomerAtt() as $attId => $attLabel) {
                $this->addOption($attId, addslashes($attLabel));
            }
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an error of Mailchimp module just go to the below location

> Magento_root/vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/CustomerMap.php

On the line number 68 comment the below code

```
$optionExtraAttr['option_' . $this->_getMailchimpRenderer()->calcOptionHash($row->getData('mailchimp_field_id'))] =
            'selected="selected"';
```

Since initially your **Magento store** is not connected with the **Mailchimp** so it is not able to fetch the **Mailchimp** field values & that's why it is giving error.

Please [refer this](https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/blob/102.3.34/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/CustomerMap.php#L68-#L69)

Comment: Hi, I tried comment out the line 68 & 69. but when i tried to save at the configuration page. i still get the error page HTTP Error 500. any solution to that? thanks

Comment: 500 error means there is some problem with the syntax or the code can you please update your code here?

Comment: i add the CustomerMap.php code in the question, thank you.

Comment: after i uninstall the mailchimp extension, remove mailchimp and mailchimp-lib from composer, then i install this version (for magento 2.2.x) "composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2:101.2.34" after that, i apply your solution above (comment out the line 68,69). Everything works now. I'll pick your answer as a solution, thank you

Comment: You are always welcome @KrisWen !! happy to help you :)!!

Answer (score 2):

The error says that the return data type in select is **`Array`** but it has been printed as a string. To resolve this, you have to change the way return type is printed using **`print_r`** function.

Comment: Hi, i tried that,but still getting the same error message. can you help? thanks.

Comment: you did like this `return print_r('%u', crc32($this->getName() . $this->getId() . $optionValue));` ?

Comment: yes, that's what i did.

Comment: I see no error on your CustomerMap.php code

Comment: The best thing I can think of is to reinstall your MailChimp

Comment: thanks, i will try again with that tomorrow. i updated the question with the php error log. "[21-Mar-2019 06:54:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Helper\Data::serialize() in /public_html/vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/Helper/VarsMap.php:99 Stack trace:" does this help?

Comment: yeah it throws that error because of the array to string conversion

Comment: thanks, i replace with this version "mailchimp/mc-magento2:101.2.34" , then i had to apply the fix from @ABHISHEK TRIPATHI to get it work. thank you both.

Comment: that's great @Kris :) enjoy coding

Comment: you are alwasy welcome @KrisWen !! Happy to help!